# Find address of static field in WinDbg w/ SOS

Tags: .net, static, windbg, memory-address, sos

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get to the address of a static .NET class member using WinDBG w/ SOS.  Given an input program like this:

```
namespace windg_static_test
{
    class StaticTest
    {
        public static bool static_bool_field = true;
        public void show_and_set()
        {
            while (static_bool_field)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("static_bool_field = " + static_bool_field + "\nEnter new value: ");
                static_bool_field = Console.ReadLine()[0] == '0' ? false : true;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StaticTest st = new StaticTest();
            st.show_and_set();
        }
    }
}
```

I can find the EEClass using !name2ee, and I can view the values using !dumpclass w/ the name2ee value.

```
0:004> !dumpclass 1c12e0
Class Name:      windg_static_test.StaticTest
mdToken:         02000002
File:            C:\Develop\Projects\windg static test\bin\Release\windg static test.exe
Parent Class:    64f84920
Module:          001c2e94
Method Table:    001c3844
Vtable Slots:    4
Total Method Slots:  6
Class Attributes:    100000  
Transparency:        Critical
NumInstanceFields:   0
NumStaticFields:     1
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
65377208  4000001       1f       System.Boolean  1   static        1 static_bool_field
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to get the address that the value is actually stored at.  How is this done, in general?

Thanks,
Eglin

Comment: What version of .NET are you debugging?

Comment: Oh, gosh!  I'm sorry - I tried so hard to make a complete question, and failed badly.  I'm using 4.5 on Win 7 x64, compiling for "Any CPU", and using the 32 bit version of WinDbg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poking around the disassembly allowed me to see the static values being picked up from the .data segment.  I wasn't able to figure out how to formulate a general-purpose solution to get the correct location from the offset that !dumpclass/!dumpobj give you for value-types, but the indexes do work fine for static reference type members on the heap once you figure out the base pointer.  I'm guessing I'd have to delve into the details of the PE format to get better information on how information is stored in the .data segments, although I'm not exactly sure where to start or if it's worth pursuing at this point.

Thanks for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 5):

SOS does not display the address of the field.  Use !sosex.mdt instead.
!sosex.mdt windbg_static_test.StaticTest.

Comment: I'm sure your extension is wonderful, but I would much prefer an answer such as, "look at offset 7c of the eeclass" if such a thing exists.  How do you find the address in your WinDBG extension?

Comment: It's much more complex than that and it is different for every major version of the runtime.  Statics are stored in per-domain or per-thread arrays.  There's a location in memory that gives the address of the start of the statics for the domain/thread and then an offset stored within the class.  This is undocumented information, and since I work for MS now, I can't document it here.

Comment: Additionally, it depends on whether a class is shared or not and also whether it is a dynamic class.  It would take considerable code review  for me to even remember the algorithms.

Comment: I understand that "there's a location in memory that gives the address of the start of the statics" for the static value types and another for the static instance types - my question, specifically, asked how to determine the address.  If you don't know the answer or are for whatever reason unwilling to contribute, why bother to post at all?

Answer (score 1):

SOS displays the address only if it is a reference type object. For int,bool it directly shows the value since they are value type